# UTF-16 strings in COM

Tags: go

Please, somebody, explain Go pointers magic
I try to call COM function

```
func (p *IServer) Authorize(user, pass string) error {
  UserName := ole.SysAllocString(login.UserName)
  defer ole.SysFreeString(UserName)
  UserPsw := ole.SysAllocString(login.UserPsw)
  defer ole.SysFreeString(UserPsw)  

  // HRESULT IServer::Authorize([in] BSTR UserName, [in] BSTR UserPsw, [out] VARIANT* SID, [out, retval] long* Result)
  hr, _, _ := Call(p.VTable().Authorize,
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(p)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(UserName)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(UserPsw)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sid)),
    uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&res)))

   ...
}
```

This code works well, but when I replace convertion to

```
UserName := syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(login.UserName)
UserPsw := syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(login.UserPsw)
```

It cause an ACCESS VIOLATION! Source from go-ole

```
func SysAllocString(v string) (ss *int16) {
  pss, _, _ := procSysAllocString.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(v))))
  ss = (*int16)(unsafe.Pointer(pss))
  return
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: In C/C++ wchar* pointer works corretly both 386/amd64

```
void Authorize(IServer* p wchar* user, wchar* pass) {
   p.Authorize(user, pass ....
}
```

Comment: SysAllocString returns bstr type (with what com works). It's the same utf16 encoded string but it has 4 byte prefix, which contain its size. You can do it manually, but it might require padding which may break such idea.

Comment: https://doxygen.reactos.org/df/d5c/oleaut_8c_source.html#l00084

Comment: @LaevusDexter very good point! forgot about size prefix... 4 byte 386, 8 byte x64 will use uint prefix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SysAllocString returns BSTR type, the com type object.

```c
 typedef struct {
 #ifdef _WIN64
     DWORD pad;
 #endif
     DWORD size;
     union {
         char ptr[1];
         WCHAR str[1];
         DWORD dwptr[1];
     } u; // take it as a starting point of the string 
 } bstr_t;
```

In other words, it's the same utf16 encoded string but with the prefix in the form of its size (length of the Unicode characters multiplied by the size of wchar_t (2-4 byte)). For the optimization reason, it also has padding.

Because of its floating size, it's better to use ole package rather than reinventing the wheel. If you want to implement it yourself, and wchar_t has the size of int16 (2 bytes), then you have to do the following:

(half-pseudocode, I didn't test it)

```golang
type BSTR *uint16

func SysAllocString(str string) (result BSTR) {
    // DWORD == int32 == rune
    const padf = "\x00" // only for 64 bit system
    const sizef = "\x00"

    // int32 == 4 byte 
    // int16 == 2 byte
    const wordSize = unsafe.Sizeof(int16(0))

    utf16 := utf16.Encode([]rune(padf + sizef + str))

    /* pad is on index 0 and 1 */
    size :=  &utf16[2 /* 0 for 32 bit system */]

    // set "size" field as unicode charachers length multypled by size of wchar_t
    *(*rune)(unsafe.Pointer(size)) = rune((len(utf16)-2) * int(wordSize))


    result = BSTR(&utf16[0])

    return
}

// ...
bstr := SysAllocString(login.UserName)

uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(bstr))
```